# Does iOS support a DNS cache accessible by an API?

Tags: ios, caching, dns, core-foundation

I'm currently using the [asynchronous CFHost method](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/ResolvingDNSHostnames.html) of resolving hosts when necessary, but in certain cases, it can happen pretty frequently.

I haven't seen anything in this documentation that mentions using built in caches and I'd rather not implement one myself if there is another method of checking a DNS cache that iOS is managing somewhere else.

Is there a different API that exposes a DNS cache?